# "s3cmd get" for only changed files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, s3cmd

I need to run the `s3cmd get` command every day and only download the changed files (if any). There's this `--skip-existing` option which skips the already existing files but it doesn't check whether the file on S3 has changed in contents or not.

Is there way to get only changed files with `s3cmd`? Or alternatively, I can use `aws-cli` too if it has such option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

This is available in both `s3cmd` and `aws s3` cli.

```
s3cmd sync <s3Uri> <LocalPath>
```

Or

```
aws s3 sync <s3Uri> <LocalPath>
```

Comment: Oh, silly me! I didn't know I was able to `sync` to local. Thanks a bunch!